# Python module to cross platform monitor system statistics?

Tags: python, cross-platform, system-monitoring, systemmanagement

I'm looking for a python module that will allow me to monitor and log the system statistics of 4 computers.  I need this module to be able to:

- Work on at least Windows and Debian Linux
- Monitor disk usage, memory usage, network usage, cpu load, and core temperature (if available)

Unfortunately, I haven’t been able to find a module that satisfies either qualifier, and I want to avoid wrapping python around another language to accomplish this.

If anyone has anything remotely close to what I'm describing, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/)?  You can build all sorts of [plugins in Python](http://samuelks.com/python-munin/) as well, plus [many already exist](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/plugins).

Comment: Hm, It does do what I need, (and then some), but looking at the documentation makes it seem pretty bulky, and speed is critical in my script, Do you think this will be an issue?

Comment: We use it on all of our real-time clusters right now without any issue. Maybe pare down the configuration to only show what it is you need to.  I can't say for sure if it will meet your needs, though... but I'd be interested in your findings if you want to share them.

Comment: All right, Sounds good then, and I’d be more than happy to share how things go, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe WMI is what you need. See link below for reference.

[Python_WMI](https://pypi.org/project/WMI/)